# Aussprache von »Kaffee«

Tags: pronunciation, regional, stress

Warum wird in Deutschland (zumindest in den meisten Teilen Deutschlands) die erste Silbe des Worts »Kaffee« betont, und die zweite Silbe eher kurz ausgesprochen?

In Österreich wird die zweite Silbe betont und lang gesprochen, und das entspricht auch dem, was man aus der Aussprache aller anderen Wörter ableiten kann, die mit Doppel-e enden.

Einige Beispiele:

einsilbige Wörter:

> Fee, Klee, Lee, See, Schnee, Tee

zweisilbige Wörter:

> Armee, Idee, Klischee, Moschee

Warum ist das nur beim Wort *»Kaffee«* anderes? Und warum auch nicht im gesamten Sprachraum?

Comment: Für mich (sprachsozialisiert in Süddeutschland, doch kein Dialektsprecher) ist "Kafffe" mit kurzem (und unbetontem) e eine Sitte bzw. Unsitte von Sprechern aus dem relativen Norden, tendenziell Nordwesten / Ruhrgebiet. Saubere Aussprache (Bühne, Radio) würde ein langes und betontes e verlangen. - Es überrascht mich, dass du findest, dass "Kafffe" in den meisten Teilen Deutschlands zu hören sei. Hast du einen Beleg?

Comment: PS: Wenn's so ist, dann würde ich vermuten: Sehr verbreitet ist die Variante, das Wort auf der ersten Silbe zu betonen. Und wenn man das tut, schlampert man sicher leicht mit der Länge des e am Ende. - Beim Kaffee mag das schneller passieren als bei der Moschee, weil man Kaffee üblicherweise ungefähr 20 Mal am Tag sagt, Moschee aber nur dreimal pro Jahr.

Comment: Ich glaube auch, es liegt mehr an der Betonung, nicht undedingt an der Länge. In Österreich wird die letzte Silbe betont [kaˈfeː], in weiten Teilen Deutschlands die erste [ˈkafe].

Comment: Beim ins Café gehen spreche ich das e länger aus, als beim Kaffeetrinken. Beim Kaffee ist es aber nicht anders als bei der Armee oder dem Klischee. Zählt Moselfranken schon zu Norddeutschland?

Comment: Ich werfe mal das 'Käffchen' in den Raum, das mit einem Kaffee mit langem "e" wohl nicht zu bilden wäre. Das bedeutet sicher etwas.

Comment: Die Uni Augsburg hat eine interessante Karte dazu. Interessanterweise scheinen die Betonungsvarianten von "Kaffee" ziemlich deckungsgleich verteilt mit denen von "Tabak": https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_4/f23a-c/

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Aus S-W-Deutschland kenne ich Kaffee nur mit Betonung auf der ersten Silbe *und* langem *e*. Ein kurzes *e* am Ende empfinde ich entschieden als einen Hinweis auf einen Dialekt nördlicherer Herkunft. Von einer auf der ersten Silbe betonten Moschee erfahre ich in deinem Kommentar dennoch zum allerersten Mal.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich hatte den Aspekt der Betonung völlig außer Acht gelassen, und habe meine Frage nun entsprechend angepasst. Angeregt zu dieser Frage wurde ich heute durch eine [Dokumentation](http://www.servustv.com/at/Medien/Die-geheime-Welt-des-Essens3), die zwar in einem österreichischen Fernsehsender (servus.tv) lief, aber offenbar in Deutschland produziert wurde, und bei der es ab ca. 21 Minuten nach Beginn der Sendung um Kaffee und Koffein ging.

Comment: Im Norden gibt es beides: Káffee trinkt man im Café.

Comment: @Janka. Das ist eigentlich auch im Süden so zu hören. Aber was ich so im Ohr habe, hat auch der vornbetonte Káffee dort noch sein langes e.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die vornbetonte Moschee war ja nur ein hypothetisches Beispiel...

Comment: @Tofro: Außer Kaffee, Tabak und Tunnel (in den Augsburger Karten) wäre auch der Beton einer Kartierung wert. Es gibt bekanntermaßen die Aussprachevariante mit Hintenbetonung (typisch im Norden, dann meist mit -ng am Ende: Betóng) und die mit Vornebetonung (Béton), die wohl nur im Süden heimisch ist (im Schwäbischen oft Béddo).

Comment: Meinst du die "United Colors of Béton"? Grau, Grau, Grau, Grauslich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das kurze E (Kaffe) hört man zwar, aber ich verstehe die Frage eher so, als sei das E lang, aber das kurze A betont. So, als hätte das Wort "Trasse" zusätzlich ein langes E

Comment: An denjenigen, der die Frage mit der Begründung »primarily opinion-based« geschlossen haben möchte: Inwiefern hängt die Ursache eines Ausspracheunterschieds von jemandes Meinung ab?

Answer (score 6):

Die Betonung von eingedeutschten Wörtern *kann* von der Herkunft bzw. von der Sprache, aus denen wir Wörter übernehmen, abhängen. Sowohl "Kaffee" als auch "Tabak" sind nicht direkt aus ihren eigentlichen Ursprungssprachen (anscheinend Arabisch bzw. Südamerika) übernommen, sondern über Drittsprachen (Spanisch, Französisch, Englisch, Niederländisch) ins Deutsche eingewandert.

Wörter aus dem Englischen und aus dem Niederländischen werden im Deutschen gerne auf den ersten Silben betont, aus dem Französischen übernommene Wörter werden größtenteils endbetont:

> "coffee" <-> "café"
>
> "tobacco" <-> "tabac"
>
> "army" <-> "armée"

[Hier](https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_4/f23a-c/) finden sich zum Vergleich zwei Karten, die die Verteilung der Betonungsgewohnheiten der Sprecher für "Tabak" und "Kaffee" im deutschen Sprachraum wiedergeben: Erstaunlicherweise sind für beide Wörter die Landkarten beinahe deckungsgleich: In Deutschland und der Schweiz scheint man überwiegend den Wortanfang zu betonen, in Österreich das Ende.

Warum nun die Österreicher die eher "französische" Betonung zu bevorzugen scheinen und die Deutschen (und sogar die Schweizer) die eher "nördlichere" Betonung, dürfte nicht einfach zu klären sein. Möglicherweise hat es damit zu tun, dass man bei Lebens- und Genussmitteln den Franzosen mehr Kompetenz zuspricht bzw. sich die französische Betonungsvariante "vornehmer" anhört. Möglicherweise hat es auch mit der Nähe bzw. Verbindung zum Balkan und seinen Sprachen zu tun, die traditionell solche Wörter eher aus dem Französischen als aus dem Englischen übernehmen. Kaffee in Deutschland und der Schweiz wurde historisch eher über die Niederlande über den Rhein importiert, möglicherweise haben wir über die traditionellen Handelsrouten auch die Betonung übernommen.

Comment: Bei den Balkansprachen herrscht (wen überrascht's) ein buntes Mischmasch von mal vorn, mal hinten: káfa (Serbisch) káva (Kroatisch und Slovenisch),káhva (Bosnisch), káfe (Mazedonisch), kafé (Griechisch), kafé (Bulgarisch), káhve (Türkisch). Albanisch weiß ich jetzt nicht, aber ich vermute: vorne. Dass sich österreichische Endbetonung auf diesem Wege erklären ließe, halte ich für unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Vielleicht haben türkische Händler (*kahve*) von Osten ihren Weg über Österreich genommen?

Comment: @Takkat Kann sein, daher auch "entlang der Handelsrouten" - Die frühe Atatürk-Türkei hat im Zuge ihrer Ausrichtung nach Europa auch extrem viele Wörter aus dem Französischen übernommen. Ich weiß jetzt aber leider nicht, wie die Türken das Wort betonen. Und nochmal: Ich glaube, dass die Ursache der Betonungsunterschiede sehr schwer ergründbar ist, weil sich Betonung normalerweise halt nicht in schriftlicher Überlieferung niederschlägt.

Comment: Laut [Peiffer Etymologisches Wörterbuch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kaffee) wird kahve endbetont, das würde passen.

Comment: Dann hat @ChristianGeiselmann oben geschwindelt...

Comment: Mein Türkischlehrer an der Uni lehrte, dass es in türkischen Wörtern gar keine eigentliche (deutlich hörbare, wichtige) Betonung gebe. Aus der Sprachpraxis heraus würde ich aber sagen, dass es wenn überaupt, beim Kaffee dann doch die vordere Silbe ist. Um so mehr, wenn man dann agglutiniert: *türk kahvesi* - ist unbedingt *türk káhvesi*, nicht *türk kahvési*. Aber letztlich müssten hier Berufenere sprechen, denn für mich gilt in Bezug aufs Türkische: *hepsi unuttum!* (hab alles vergessen).

Comment: Diese Antwort betrachtet die Betonung auf der ersten oder zweiten Silbe, geht aber offenbar nicht auf das lange oder kurze *e* am Ende ein.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das ist richtig - ich habe selbstverständlich angenommen, dass das eine sich aus dem anderen ergibt. Ich finde, ohne meine Sprache zu verbiegen, keine Möglichkeit, die erste Silbe zu betonen und trotzdem ein langes "e" zu sprechen.

Comment: @tofro: Aus Südwestdeutschland kenne ich eigentlich ausschließlich die Aussprache, in der die erste Silbe betont ist *und* das *e* lang gesprochen wird. Ein kurzes *e* ist ein eindeutiger Hinweis auf eine nördlichere Herkunft des Sprechers, während die Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe dem Café, der gastronomischen Einrichtung, vorbehalten ist. Ich sehe bei der Betonung auf der ersten Silbe und langem *e* auch kein Ausspracheproblem; *Kaffee* reimt sich auf *Eisfee* und auf *Bergsee*.

Comment: @tofro. - Doch, doch, man kann schon einen Vokal in der ersten Silben betonen und dann trotzdem auch noch einen Vokal in einer folgenden Silbe lang aussprechen. Oder jedenfalls die Finnen können's (Betonung regelhaft auf der ersten Silbe, und die kann kurz sein, und danach kommen dann allerlei schöne lange Vokale in unbetonten Silben). Ach, übrigens, wie sprichst du den schönen Namen Dorothee aus? Ich: Betonung auf der ersten Silbe, und ee am Ende trotzdem lang.

Answer (score 5):

Nachdem ich [tofros Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/39198/1487) und Takkats Kommentare darauf gelesen hatte, ging mir ein Licht auf, und eine kurze Recherche bestätigte meine Vermutung, die leider zu lang für einen Kommentar ist, weswegen ich sie als Antwort schreibe:

Der Kaffee erreichte den deutschen Sprachraum über zwei unterschiedliche Routen:

Die erste Kaffeehäuser im deutschsprachigen Raum standen in Bremen (1673) und Hamburg (1675). Der Kaffee, der dort verkauft wurde, wurde auf dem Seeweg angeliefert, und offenbar waren es ganz friedliche britische Händler, die nicht nur die Bohnen, sondern auch das Wort *coffee* brachten. In J.S.Bachs sogenannter »Kaffeesonate« (tatsächlicher Titel: »Schweigt stille, plaudert nicht«, BWV 211) aus dem Jahr 1732 wird auch immer wieder vom »Coffee« gesungen:

> ...
>
> Herr Vater, seid doch nicht so scharf!
>   Wenn ich des Tages nicht dreimal
>   Mein Schälchen Coffee trinken darf,
>   So werd ich ja zu meiner Qual
>   Wie ein verdorrtes Ziegenbrätchen.
>
> Ei! wie schmeckt der Coffee süße,
>   Lieblicher als tausend Küsse,
>   Milder als Muskatenwein.
>   Coffee, Coffee muss ich haben,
>   Und wenn jemand mich will laben,
>   Ach, so schenkt mir Coffee ein!
>
> ...

Das englische Wort mischte sich mit dem Französischen *café*, und zwar so, dass die französischen Vokale (Vokal der ersten Silbe = a), und die englische Betonung (erste Silbe betont) zusammenfanden.

Bevor der Kaffee auf dem Landweg bis nach Wien kam, geschah dort aber etwas anderes: 1683 (10 Jahre nach dem ersten Bremer Kaffeehaus) drangen die Türken bis nach Wien vor und belagerten die Stadt. Die Türken wurden allerdings geschlagen, und so gelangten die Wiener in den Besitz einiger Säcke Kaffee, und sie übernahmen auch den türkischen Namen *kahve*, der allem Anschein nach eher auf der zweiten Silbe betont wurde. Dazu gibt es auch eine schöne Legende, die man in den Kaffeekarten mancher Wiener Kaffeehäuser nachlesen kann, die aber frei erfunden sein dürfte, weshalb ich sie hier auch nicht wiedergebe.

Tatsache ist aber, das 2 Jahre danach, im Jahr 1685, ein Armenier das erste Kaffeehaus in Wien eröffnet hat. Da Türkisch damals noch mit arabischer Schrift geschrieben wurde, konnte nur die Aussprache übernommen werden. Da sie aber sehr gut zu dem aus Norddeutschland kommenden geschriebenen Wort passte, wurde diese Schreibweise auch im Süden üblich.

**Zusammengefasst:**

- Die Bohnen selbst kamen im Norden über den Seeweg als normales Handelsgut, im Süden aber als "Mitbringsel" eines türkischen Feldzuges in den deutschen Sprachraum.
- Das geschriebene Wort stammt aus dem englischen, hat aber auch einen starken französischen Einfluss.
- Das gesprochene Wort kam im Norden aus dem Englischen (mit dem bereits erwähnten französischen Einfluss), während es im Süden aus dem Türkischen kam.

Comment: In Bachs Autograph steht aber "Coffe": https://www.bach-digital.de/rsc/viewer/BachDigitalSource_derivate_00002401/db_bachp0141_page005.jpg

Comment: @fdb: Tatsächlich, du hast Recht. Aber das beweist eben nur umso mehr, dass die zweite Silbe schon im 18. Jahrhundert in Thüringen und Sachsen kurz und unbetont war.